# Supplymentary header view not taking to status bar collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, header, cell

I make this screen with collection view with using supplementary HeaderView. I want to make this HeaderView to the status bar. I make clear color to status bar but it is not working. Please help me with it.[image]

Comment: You want to hide status bar?

Comment: @AlexanderKolovatov If I hide status bar then my header view take position in status bar?

Comment: Yes, your header originY will be equal 0. If you need a code example I can write it for you.

Comment: ok then give me solution, I will try it @AlexanderKolovatov

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the next, delete this view and put this image in the back of the navigation bar, the next is putting navigation bar transparent and the tint color in white like this :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the contents of the collection view started earlier.

```
collectionView.contentInset.top = -14
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all in your info.plst tap "+" button and this line.
[image]

Than in your UIViewController add this method.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Status bar will be hidden only in this viewController.